# How to get the value from javascript to php variable when script and php code are in index.php?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

My code in index.php is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){

        function callback(position) {
           latitude = position.coords.latitude;
           longitude = position.coords.longitude;
             alert(latitude);
             alert(longitude);
        }

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback);
        }

    }
</script>
```

i need to display the value of latitude and longitude in index.php

```
<?php echo $lat; ?>, 
<?php echo $long; ?> how can i get value here?
```

Comment: Asynchronous HTTP request (AJAX). Maybe Websocket. Cannot be passed client side (as you are expecting).

Comment: you cannot assign directly javascript variable to php variable, use cookie to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Javascript is client based language and you can not send it to server unless you refresh your page or use AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript And Xml)

**AJAX** just uses a combination of:

- A browser built-in XMLHttpRequest object (to request data from a web server)
- JavaScript and HTML DOM (to display or use the data)*

You can create one controller where you will send your data like this for

```
function sendData(lat, lon) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      alert("Sent successfuly");
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getGeolocation.php?latitude=" + lat + "&longitude=" + lon , true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

This way you will pass latitude and longitude by function and then send its values to your controller in getGeolocation.php

You can fetch data like this

```
$lat = $_GET['lat'];
$lon = $_GET['lon'];
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I really confused n couldnt get the solution yet. I need this  value on loading single-service.php. Can you give me full code.